# Baffling error where FactoryGirl object has incorrect data, but only locally

Tags: ruby, debugging, rspec, factory-bot

This is baffling me and everyone else at the office.

I have a factory girl insert like this:

```
@data = FactoryGirl.create(:'database/table',
                                             :packagemember_tp => 3
)
puts 'kanga'
puts @data.packagemember_tp
puts 'kanga'
```

Looks fine, but the log that prints out is this:

```
kanga
2
kanga
```

No matter what value I tell it to insert, the value is always 2.

You might think that if I opened the Factory there would be some weird default value or something, but this isn't the case:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :'database/table' do
  end
end
```

Then you might think, maybe the table DDL is a weird data type, but this isn't the case:

```
PackageMember_Tp SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
```

Then you think, let's put a breakpoint in there and examine the object and see what the real value is:

```
@values = Hash (17 element(s))
...
packagemember_tp => 2
```

Then finally you think, well let's check the log again for the actual SQL insert statement and see the number that's being inserted?

```
INSERT INTO database.table (PACKAGEMEMBER_TP) VALUES (3)
```

So what is going on?

Why are all values for this column being translated to 2's, but only in the local FactoryGirl object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the error.

So, the primary key of that table was not unique.

After FG does the insert, it does `sel top 1 * from table` with the primary key that you specify.

Since that key was not unique, there were other rows in the table with that value.

One of those rows was returned, and it just happened to have a 2 in that column.